# MDL Attribute Evaluation in Python

Tags: correlation, feature-selection

Is there any implementation of MDL method introduced in (Kononenko, 1995) with favorable bias for multi-valued and multi-class problems in Python? Are there any libraries?

I am trying to implement CFS (correlation-based feature selection) with three methods: Symmetrical Uncertainty, Relief, and MDL. There's a similar function in R called "attrEval". However, I have plenty of implementation problems in this programming language, and it made me give up.